# CSS - Cannot override font-style in Dropdown

Tags: css

I am trying to put custom styling only on the visible item when the drop down is closed, but not the items inside the drop down.

To do this, I put custom styling on `select`, then undo them on `option`. For example, I have `font-style: italic` set on a `select` element. But webkit browsers and IE10 seems to ignore font-style overrride.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
option {
    color: black; // undos color:red
    font-style: normal!important; // This should undo the italic font style.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XTLX/)

Why do those browsers ignore the font-style override even with `!important`? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select boxes have very poor css styling support on all browsers.

To have total control of select box styling you will have to use a javascript solution to replace the select box with something that can be styled. http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/ is one option, or you might be best off looking at a jQuery plugin or Bootstrap.

Comment: Yep, you'd have thought if the web community can find solutions to the problem then the browser developers would be able too!

Answer (score 0):

What I found through Google was that the option elements are in fact styled by the OS, and can therefore not be styled through CSS (without JavaScript hacks or such).